# Laravel Return NULL when uploading large files

Tags: php, apache, laravel, file-upload

My Form

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'upfile', 'files' => 'true', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form')) }}
        <p>Sólo se admiten archivos en formato .pdf y no mayor a 127MB</p>
        <p>
        {{ Form::file('expediente', array('class' => 'text-field column_one', 'required' => 'required')) }}
        </p><br>
        <p>
        {{ Form::text('nombrearchivo', null, array('class' => 'text-field column_one', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre del Expediente.')) }}
        </p><br>

        {{ Form::hidden('username', $username) }}

        <p style="color: red;">
            <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
                <li style="color:red;">{{$message}}</li>
            @endforeach
            <ul>
        </p>
        {{ Form::submit('Añadir Expediente', array('class' => 'submit submitNavy submitForm')) }}
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

My Controller:

```
public function saveExpediente(){
    ini_set("memory_limit","7G");
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '127M');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '127M');
    ini_set('max_input_time', 0);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|exists:users,username',
        'expediente' => 'required',
        'nombrearchivo'    =>  'required|min:5'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    //$fileExtension = Input::file('expediente')->guessClientExtension();
    $file = Input::file('expediente');
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //dd($file);
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput(); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    }/*else if ($fileExtension != 'pdf'){
        $validator->failed();
        return Redirect::to('upload')->withErrors([
            'expediente' => 'El archivo debe estar en formato PDF!',
        ])->withInput();
    }*/else {

        File::makeDirectory('expedientes/'.Input::get('username'), 0770, true, true);
        Input::file('expediente')->move('expedientes/'.Input::get('username'),Input::file('expediente')->getClientOriginalName());

        $expediente = new Expediente;
        $expediente->username =  Input::get('username');
        $expediente->archivo = Input::file('expediente')->getClientOriginalName();
        $expediente->nombrearchivo = Input::get('nombrearchivo');
        $expediente->save();

        return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Se añadió correctamente el expediente al usuario.')->with('tipo','message-success');
    }
}
```

When I'm uploading bigger than 8mb laravel returning NULL, like fields they were empty. I already got the value of variables PHP.init. I'm use Laravel 4.2 and Apache, need upload files size with 25-40 mb. If I try dd(Input::file('expediente')) return NULL

Comment: Do you check your maximum upload file size in php.ini?

Comment: And post_max_size too?

Comment: Oh.. Not! It's 7MB... Now we are sure this it's the problem. The App it's at a share-server. Can't we change variable value without contacting to Company support?

Comment: You can't use 'ini_set" for that. You have to contact your host company for that. Maybe they have a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the memory limit of file upload. You could do this by mentioning the limit size in the beginning of the controller.

ini_set('memory_limit', 'size');

For example:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '40M');`

You may also need to mention the `enctype` (encoding type) in the form

Example:-

`{{ Form::open(array(
         'url' => 'upfile', 
         'method' => 'post', 
         'class' => 'form', 
         'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
     )) 
  }}`

and may be you dont need this 
`'files' => 'true'`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the error:

   `$request->file('image')->getErrorMessage()`
2. If error looks like:

   `The file "image_name.jpeg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB)`
3. In blank page execute the next command to locate php.ini:

   `<?php phpinfo() ?>`
4. In php.ini file edit the next lines:

   `post_max_size`

   `upload_max_filesize`
5. Increase the memory limit (by default is 2M), you can try with 10M.